# dhtmlxScheduler timelineview calender loading and displaying data

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using dhtmlxScheduler timelineview calender. I am getting xml data from database but not able to load it out on calender.

Comment: What language are you using on your server?

Comment: I know how to do it in C# - can't help you with PHP though :-(

Answer (score 0):

firstly you will need to use DHTMLX's connector(server side, to load the data) and data-processor(client side, to update data.

See [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__index.html) for more information on the connector.

So you will need how to use the PHP connector with the Scheduler. You can view DHTMLX's documentation on that [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/server_integration.html). And in this [how-to](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/how_to_start.html) they explain step-by-step how to load data from a database, and how it should be structured.

And [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/guides.html) is just some basic documentation on the scheduler API that will be very useful.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Let me know if you need help.

Regards.

Comment: I am using the DHTMLX's connector. My data is loaded from the events.php file.
It is working when I write day,month and week. But not load data when I write timeline.
scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(),"timeline"); // day,month,week,timeline
scheduler.setLoadMode("timeline");

Comment: I have not used the setLoadMode method. However looking at the documentation. You are passing it an incorrect mode value. Have a look at the link below, change it and let me know what happens.

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_setloadmode.html